# Automatic seperation by n*n faces on a large plane in python?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm by no means a programmer, but I see no other way to do this.

[image]

I need it to separate every 11*11 (or n*n) faces
like that
but not having to do it manually
(since there are a ton and this workflow will repeat)

just being able to select one corner, the other corner, and have it seperate every 11 x 11 chunks for me the best it can.

Kind of like a reverse array modifier?

I'd really appreciate this. Thank you.

Comment: If it were a reverse array modifier would end up with **one** n x n mesh arrayed.  Or do you want an array of separate objects, all with individual meshes, cut from the original?   If the original mesh is a plane, simplest solution (as previously answered and removed) would be to add a new n x n grid and array it.